# Get angular component for given HTML element in production

Tags: angular

Is it possible to obtain the angular component instance from a given HTML element (representing an angular component) in production without passing it through `@Output`?

E.g.

```
const el = document.querySelector('...')!;
const elComponent = somehowGetComponentInstanceFor(el);
```

`ng.getComponent` should not work for production builds according to https://angular.io/api/core/global:

> [...] These functions are not exposed when the application runs in a production mode.

(I can't use `@ViewChild` and i don't want to introduce a long `@Output`-chain.)